# php alert message upload successful

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
  $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['name'];
  $UploadName = mt_rand (100000, 999999).$UploadName; 
  $UploadTmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['tmp_name'];
  $UploadType = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['type'];
  $FileSize = $_FILES['UploadFileField'] ['size'];
  $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);
  if(($FileSize > 1250000)){
    die ("Error - File to Big");
  }
  if(!$UploadTmp) {
    die ("No File Selected");
  }
  else {
    move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, "Upload/$UploadName");
  }
  header('Location: /index.php');
  exit;
}
?>
```

This code works, but I need insert a message of successful after that is done Upload file.
Thank you!

Comment: turn on [error checking](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php#85096)

Comment: set message in session .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, "Upload/$UploadName")) {
  $message = "Successfully inserted";
  header('Location: /index.php?success=true&message='.$message);
}
else {
  $message =  "Something went wrong";
  header('Location: /index.php?success=false&message='.$message);
}
```

use the if condition for the **move_uploaded_file** function it will help you. And get the success, message from index file

```
if ($_GET['success'] == true) {
    echo $_GET['message'];
 }
```

Or you can use the SESSION

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter when you redirect like :

```
header('Location: /index.php?upload=true');
```

And in your index check if you get the parameter and display a message if it's the case and if it's where you want to display the message. You can check also with if else statement if the upload work and change the var to sent